CreateProcess not creating process
I was working with Windows calls, and I had to program a CreateProcess function. After reviewing the expected parameters, I haven't been able to put it to work. I think it may be due to the command line, due to it giving me error code 2.
I am using Visual Studio 2022, and it requires using the type LPWSTR in the command line argument of the function, I don't know if that's related.
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, PCHAR argv[])
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    GetStartupInfo(&si);

    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    if (argv[1] == 0) {
        printf("42");
        return 3;
    }

    printf("%s\n", argv[0]);
    fflush(stdout);
    printf("%d\n", atoi(argv[1]));
    fflush(stdout);

    char cmdArgs[] = "C:\\Users\\user\\source\\repos\\createProcess\\x64\\Debug\\createProcess.exe 0";

    if (!CreateProcess(NULL,
        (LPWSTR)cmdArgs,      
        NULL,          
        NULL,          
        FALSE,        
        0,             
        NULL,           
        NULL,           
        &si,           
        &pi)           
        )
    {
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
        printf("\nProcess created\n");
    }
}

I am passing a 1 as an argument.
What I think should happen is it should execute, print the first argument, the path and name of the .exe (from where I got the path), the second argument (to ensure it is being passed on correctly), then I create the command line, with backslashes before the normal backslashes so that it doesn't misread anything, then create the process with a 0 as its argument, and then wait for the new process to end.
The new process should just print 42 and end.
Instead, it just throws the "CreateProcess failed", and ends there.

argv[1] == 0 is wrong. "0" in args in not int 0.

While you are right, my problem is that it doesn't even start a new process, that is something I can fix later, I think

It prints "CreateProcess failed" and then what error code? But also, yeah, you can't cast a char* to LPWSTR, that's wrong. You're sending garbage to CreateProcess.

The error code is 2, I thought I wrote it.

But yes, perhaps the error is there, how can one declare and assign a value to LPWSTR?
